# Two DateTimes: one works, why doesn't the other?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

In my app I receive some json from Facebook.
If I try this:

```
utente.birthday = ((objectParsed.birthday != null) ? DateTime.Parse((string)objectParsed.birthday) : (DateTime?)null);
```

With the Date as:

```
"birthday": "01\/01\/1996"
```

It works correctly, but if the Date is:

```
"birthday": "09\/23\/1982",
```

I get `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` exception. Where does it go wrong?

Comment: Probably the date format in your regional settings (which is used by default in DateTime.Parse unless you specify otherwise) is dd/MM/yyyy, which obviously fails when given 23 as a month number. Try using custom DateTime format instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Because the first is ambiguous in month and day, the second one is not ambiguous as the first number is month and the second is day because there are not 23 months. The first example can be either. If the first was "01\/02\/2013" that could be 1st Feb or 2nd Jan depending on how you parse it. You are using the computer's current culture to parse, which I guess is day / month / year.

Comment: What is your culture by the way?

Comment: My Culture? I'm from Italy, but the json data are from america I guess. So Culture en-US right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's culture issue. In the second date, the month day (23) was mismatched for the month.

Use `ParseExact()` with format `MM/dd/yyyy` or specify the culture to the parser.

Answer (score 2):

Because your default DateTime format specified by culture is accepting other format probably with `dd/MM/yyyy`

use ParseExact with format:

```
MM/dd/yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass datetime as in MM-dd-YYYY format.Then it will not give exception.

```
  "MM-dd-YYYY"
```